# Slurm and Openmpi: An ORTE daemon has unexpectedly failed after launch and before communicating back to mpirun

Tags: mpi, openmpi, slurm

I have installed openmpi and slurm in two nodes. i want to use slurm to run mpi jobs. When i use `srun` to run non-mpi jobs, everything is ok. However, i got some errors when i use `salloc` to run mpi jobs. Environment and codes are as follows.

**Env:**

1. slurm 17.02.1-2
2. mpirun (Open MPI) 2.1.0

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

MACHINEFILE="nodes.$SLURM_JOB_ID"

# Generate Machinefile for mpich such that hosts are in the same
#  order as if run via srun
#
srun -l /bin/hostname | sort -n | awk '{print $2}' > $MACHINEFILE

source /home/slurm/allreduce/tf/tf-allreduce/bin/activate

mpirun -np $SLURM_NTASKS -machinefile $MACHINEFILE test

rm $MACHINEFILE
```

**command**

```
salloc -N2 -n2 bash test.sh
```

**ERROR**

```
salloc: Granted job allocation 97
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
An ORTE daemon has unexpectedly failed after launch and before
communicating back to mpirun. This could be caused by a number
of factors, including an inability to create a connection back
to mpirun due to a lack of common network interfaces and/or no
route found between them. Please check network connectivity
(including firewalls and network routing requirements).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
salloc: Relinquishing job allocation 97
```

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: for debugging purpose, can you insert in your script `srun -N $SLURM_NNODES -n $SLURM_NNODES $(which orted)`

Comment: as a side note, you do not need the `-np` nor the `machinefile` options. you can simply `mpirun ./test` (if you simply use `mpirun test`, you might inadvertently use `/usr/bin/test`)